# Spring batch - using multiple characters as delimiter

Tags: java, spring, delimiter, spring-batch

I have a input file with delimiter as "||".

As you can see there are two characters but batch accepts a single character as delimiter.

How to go about this issue??

Issue [Batch-591](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-591) in Jira shows as resolved -- Is it possible to use multiple characters as delimiter ??

Thanks,
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced issue is resolved as wont-fix. This means they don't see the necessity of this issue.

But I guess you are recommended to implement your own Tokenizer class (probably extending [`AbstractLineTokenizer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/AbstractLineTokenizer.html)), using a workaround strategy [like this one](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-591?focusedCommentId=35877&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-35877).

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer` has two constructors :

`DelimitedLineTokenizer()` is the default constructor  for the common case where the delimiter is a comma  and is invoked automatically for a single character.

`DelimitedLineTokenizer(java.lang.String delimiter)` is used when the delimiter is of multiple characters.

Specify `java.lang.String` in `constructor-arg` type.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pete it really works for me
I had to add this char "::" as a delimiter , this is  the DelimitedLineTokenizer bean set up

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value= "::"/></bean>
```